# Left and right justification and centering text in the same html table cell

Tags: html, css

I'd like to place some text in a td in an html table, with one string being flush left, another string being flush right, and the final piece of text being right in the middle (the td is wide enough to accommodate all the strings).

So far I have the following for the flush left and right text

```
.left {
    float: left
}

.right {
    float: right;
}
```

And the following:

```
  <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
       <span class="left" id="span1">Value 1</span>
       <span class="right" id="span2">Value 2</span>
   </td>
```

But I don't know how to put the last piece of text right between these two. Can anyone help please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a flexbox layout.
Wrap the spans inside a `<div>`. This element will have `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-between`.

```css
table {
  width: 600px;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    
    <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
      <div class="container">
        <span id="span1">Value 1</span>
        <span id="span2">Value 2</span>
        <span id="span3">Value 3</span>
      </div>
    </td>
    
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly! I ended up putting a unicode "vertical divider" character between the 1st and 2nd, and 2nd and 3rd spans to split up the text, even though the characters are well separated.